# VueJs can't access data property within the function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a problem accessing data property, within the function. I'm missing something and I can't figure out what.

this is my class

```
export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {
        FooterComponent: FooterComponent,
        NavigationComponent: NavigationComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            locale: Cookie.get('locale'),
            nameAndLastName: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: '',
            showPopUp: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$validator.validateAll();
            if (!this.$validator.errors.any()) {
                let params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.append('nameAndLastName', this.nameAndLastName);
                params.append('email', this.email);
                params.append('subject', this.subject);
                params.append('message', this.message);

                axios.post(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/Contact/contact`, params, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
                            console.log(this.showPopUp);
                            this.showPopUp = true;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        // This throws error TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPopUp' of undefined

                    });
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('test');
        console.log(this.showPopUp);
    },
}
```

So the problem is when I send message, the response is OK, email is sent, but I'm keep getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPopUp' of undefined`... when I try to print console.log(this.showPopUp) in mounted hook, variable is display OK, so why I can't access it from the method? I'm using VueJs 2.

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `this` inside your `.then()` callback refers to the callback itself and not to the proxied data you are looking for.

In order to make it work, you would need to assign the correct `this` context to another variable and then use this one.

That's how it looks into code:

```
export default {
    name: "Contact",
    components: {
        FooterComponent: FooterComponent,
        NavigationComponent: NavigationComponent
    },
    data() {
        return {
            locale: Cookie.get('locale'),
            nameAndLastName: '',
            email: '',
            subject: '',
            message: '',
            showPopUp: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendEmail(e) {
            var self = this: // assign context to self variable
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$validator.validateAll();
            if (!this.$validator.errors.any()) {
                let params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.append('nameAndLastName', this.nameAndLastName);
                params.append('email', this.email);
                params.append('subject', this.subject);
                params.append('message', this.message);

                axios.post(this.$apiUrl + `rest/api/public/Contact/contact`, params, {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                    }
                })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
                            console.log(this.showPopUp);
                            self.showPopUp = true; // assign it like this
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        // This throws error TypeError: Cannot read property 'showPopUp' of undefined

                    });
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('test');
        console.log(this.showPopUp);
    },
}
```

That's why `ES6` arrow functions are so useful. The `this` in there does not refer to the function itself.

So you could also use an arrow function like this:

```
.then((response) => {
  if (response.statusText === 'OK') {
    console.log(this.showPopUp);
    this.showPopUp = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Of course!!! :D omg, this was bugging me for quite some time. or i can just simple change .then(function .... to .then((response) => { and I could use this... :D silly me! :D

Comment: Another possible way would be to use `Function.prototype.bind`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Valor_ exactly. I've just edited the answer with the arrow functions approach. I can feel with you. Happened to me several times before